# How to Move Rails project from 2.3.5 to 3.2.11

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

My project has developed using rails 2.3.5 and now we are thinking to move our project to rails 3.2.11

Please give me some of the solutions on how to move our project into 3.2.11 and also let us know what are the changes we need to do for this

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently doing this and have decided to do it in steps,

```
2.3.X -> 3.0.X
3.0.X -> 3.1.X
3.1.X -> 3.2.X
```

I'm still on the first step but you might be able to combine steps 2 and 3 to `3.0.X -> 3.2.X`.

The `rails_upgrade` gem helped a lot with the first step. https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade

Check out the RailsCasts on upgrading. They've really helped me.

**Step 1:**

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/226-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-2
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/227-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-3

**Step 2:**

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/282-upgrading-to-rails-3-1

**Step 3:**

- http://railscasts.com/episodes/318-upgrading-to-rails-3-2